Question on a min inequality
Is it true that
$$
\min\left(a^2 + b^2 - \sqrt{a^4 + b^4 + 2a^2b^2\cos(x)}, b^2 + c^2 - \sqrt{b^4 + c^4 + 2b^2c^2\cos(x-y)}, a^2 + c^2 - \sqrt{a^4 + c^4 + 2a^2c^2\cos(y)}\right) \leq \frac{1}{3}
$$
for all $a, b, c, x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$?
Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Yes. Consider three vectors $A, B, C$ on the plane of lengths $|A|=a^2, |B|=b^2, |C|=c^2$ and mutual angles $x$ between $A$ and $B$, $y$ between $A$ and $C$, $x-y$ between $B$ and $C$ (angles are considered modulo $2\pi$). Then negation of your conjectured inequality reads as three inequalities like $|A|+|B|-|A+B|>1/3$, etc. Then, $2|A|+2|B|-|C|=3(|A|+|B|) -1>3|A+B|$, etc. Then,
\begin{align*}
9(|A|^2+|B|^2+|C|^2)&=\\(2|A|+2|B|-|C|)^2+(2|B|+2|C|-|A|)^2+(2|A|+2|C|-|B|)^2&>\\
9|A+B|^2+9|B+C|^2+9|A+C|^2&=\\
9(|A|^2+|B|^2+|C|^2)+9|A+B+C|^2,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.

After cancellations and taking everything to the right

Simply by opening the brackets. I added some details, is it clear now? One can see here a particular case of the four squares identity, for what it worth.

If the angle between $A$ and $B$ equals $x$, then $|A+B|^2=A^2+B^2+2|A|\cdot |B|\cdot \cos x$. Law of cosines is for $|A-B|$.

Thank you for your answer. How about $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$? Thanks a lot.

Sorry, I do not understand a specific question. Please ask a new question properly, anyway.

Ok. Please ask this as a new  question.

Remark. @Fedor Petrov's solution is very nice. We can tackle it algebraically (however, it basically the same as @Fedor Petrov's solution).
Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that
$a^2 + b^2 - \sqrt{a^4 + b^4 + 2a^2b^2\cos(x)} > \frac13$,
$b^2 + c^2 - \sqrt{b^4 + c^4 + 2b^2c^2\cos(x-y)} > \frac13$,
and $a^2 + c^2 - \sqrt{a^4 + c^4 + 2a^2c^2\cos(y)}) > \frac13$.
We have
\begin{align*}
    &(a^2 + b^2 - 1/3)^2 + (b^2 + c^2 - 1/3)^2 + (c^2 + a^2 - 1/3)^2 \\
    >{}& a^4 + b^4 + 2a^2b^2\cos(x) + b^4 + c^4 + 2b^2c^2\cos(x-y) + a^4 + c^4 + 2a^2c^2\cos(y)
\end{align*}
or
$$0 > a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + 2a^2b^2\cos(x) + 2b^2c^2\cos(x-y) + 2a^2c^2\cos(y)
$$
or
$$0 > (a^2 + b^2 \cos x + c^2 \cos y)^2 + (b^2 \sin x + c^2 \sin y)^2.$$
Contradiction.
We are done.
